# Data Tables in R: manipulating a column with/without a subset filter

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose  i have a data table

```
library(data.table)
ff=data.table(date=c("2013-01-01","2013-01-02","2013-01-03","2013-02-02"),x=c(1,2,3,4));  
setkey(ff,date)
```

Then this works `ff[,as.Date(date)]` but this doesn't `ff['2013-01-01',as.Date(date)]` the latter throwing the error

> "Error in as.Date.default(date) :    do not know how to convert 'date'
>   to class “Date”"

Comment: This works fine for me on `data.table` 1.8.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Justin pointed out, this is fixed in the next release.
A temp workaround for 1.8.10 is to daisychain the `[][]` as in:

```
 ff['2013-01-01'][, as.Date(date)]

 # or, if you want a DT back:
 ff['2013-01-01'][, list(as.Date(date))]
```